# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar la misma macro, para todas las figuras que se llaman de la misma manera en PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, macros, visual, basic

Me gustaría hacer, que todas las figuras de una presentación PowerPoint que tengan el nombre "*Botón*", te hipervinculen a la diapositiva 2. Hace poco que estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Visual Basic, así que desconozco como poder lograr esto.

```
Sub GotoSlide2()

With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Botón")

SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide 2

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hola. Si requiere ayuda realmente tienes que dar más detalles, lo poco que colocas deja muchas dudas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que recorrer todas las diapositivas y luego ejecutar tú código en cada una de ellas:

```
Sub RecorreSlides()

  Dim sld As Slide
            
  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
  
      Call GotoSlide2
  
  Next sld
                
End Sub
```